# Error when Using pandoc convert docx to pdf

Tags: pandoc

I am not very familiar with pandoc , I just use this tool to convert some docs' file type.
I normally use this command `pandoc --pdf-engine=xelatex -V linkcolor:blue -V CJKmainfont="Songti SC" X.docx -o X.pdf` And it works for most docs....
But recently, I got the following "Error message"...

```
Error producing PDF.
! Forbidden control sequence found while scanning use of \LT@nofcols.
<inserted text>
                \par
l.987 ...width - 0\tabcolsep) * \real{1.0000}}@{}}
```

If you need any more info , pls let me know...but maybe you need to tell me how... I am not techy...
Thanks for you help

Thanks @tarleb, and the problematic table's Html goes like this:

```html
<table>
<colgroup>
<col style="width: 67%" />
<col style="width: 32%" />
</colgroup>
<thead>
<tr class="header">
<th><ol type="1">
<li><blockquote>
<p>zhu</p>
</blockquote></li>
</ol>
<blockquote>
<p>由于J上有韵母er，且er为e开头，则zhu的按键为Qj</p>
</blockquote></th>
<th></th>
</tr>
<tr class="odd">
<th><ol start="2" type="1">
<li><blockquote>
<p>zhua</p>
</blockquote></li>
</ol>
<blockquote>
<p>由于Q上的ua、iu都不是a、e开头的韵母，则zhua的按键为Fq</p>
</blockquote></th>
<th><table>
<colgroup>
<col style="width: 100%" />
</colgroup>
<thead>
<tr class="header">
<th>Q <strong>zh</strong></th>
</tr>
<tr class="odd">
<th><strong>ua</strong></th>
</tr>
<tr class="header">
<th><strong>iu</strong></th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
</tbody>
</table></th>
</tr>
<tr class="header">
<th><ol start="3" type="1">
<li><blockquote>
<p>cha</p>
</blockquote></li>
</ol>
<blockquote>
<p>由于S上的a为a、e本身开头的韵母，则cha的按键为Ws</p>
</blockquote></th>
<th><table>
<colgroup>
<col style="width: 100%" />
</colgroup>
<thead>
<tr class="header">
<th>S <strong>zh</strong></th>
</tr>
<tr class="odd">
<th><strong>a</strong></th>
</tr>
<tr class="header">
<th><strong>ia</strong></th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
</tbody>
</table></th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: This appears to be a problem in a table. Can you try to find the problematic table? Create a new document and copy each table over one by one until the conversion no longer works. Then convert that table to HTML with `pandoc  X.docx -o x.html` and add it to the question. Also, can you run `pandoc --version` and post the result of that?

Comment: @tarleb Wow how can you know it is the "table" problem? I find that table, and my pandoc version is `pandoc 2.19.2
Compiled with pandoc-types 1.22.2.1, texmath 0.12.5.2, skylighting 0.13,
citeproc 0.8.0.1, ipynb 0.2, hslua 2.2.1
Scripting engine: Lua 5.4`

Comment: Thank you for the updates @KantDong, I can reproduce the issue with the given table! Pandoc appears to have problems with the nested table. After a bit of digging, I found an [open issue](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/3586) in pandoc's bug tracker that appears to be the same problem. We may be able to fix it with a Lua filter for now, let see if I can come up with something useful.

Comment: @tarleb Although I am not able to understand what you may fix it with , I am expecting it to be realized XD

Answer (score 0):

Below is a [pandoc Lua filter](https://pandoc.org/lua-filters.html) that should help to get the document compiled with LaTeX: it unwraps the nested tables and merges them into the top-level table.

The code isn't particularly pretty, and it does *not* offer a general solution for nested tables, but should work ok in the case at hand.

The filter can be used by saving it to a file `unnest-table.lua` and then passing it to pandoc via `--lua-filter=unnested-table.lua`.

```lua
local function allrows (tbl)
  local rows = pandoc.List{}
  rows:extend(tbl.head.rows)
  tbl.bodies:map(function (body) rows:extend(body.body) end)
  rows:extend(tbl.foot.rows)
  return rows
end

local function nested_rows (cell)
  local tbl = cell.contents[1]
  if tbl and tbl.t == 'Table' then
    return allrows(tbl)
  end
  return nil
end

function Table (tbl)
  local newhead = pandoc.TableHead()
  for i, row in ipairs(tbl.head.rows) do
    for j, cell in ipairs(row.cells) do
      local currow = row:clone()
      local nested_rows = nested_rows(cell)
      if nested_rows and #nested_rows > 0 then
        for jj=1, j-1 do
          currow.cells[jj].row_span = row.cells[jj].row_span + #nested_rows - 1
        end
        local firstnested = table.remove(nested_rows, 1)
        -- assume the nested table only has a single row
        currow.cells[j] = firstnested.cells[1]
        newhead.rows:insert(currow)
        newhead.rows:extend(nested_rows)
        goto continue
      end
    end
    newhead.rows:insert(row)
    ::continue::
  end
  tbl.head = newhead
  return tbl
end
```

Comment: Hi @tarleb thanks for your code. I tried both ways. 1st I  put the lua file in the same directory of the   .docx and then `pandoc --pdf-engine=xelatex --lua-filter=unnested-table.lua -V CJKmainfont="Songti SC" keydo.docx -o keydopandoc.pdf` . 2ndly , I tried to use a absolute path: `pandoc --pdf-engine=xelatex --lua-filter=/absolutePath/to/unnested-table.lua -V CJKmainfont="Songti SC" keydo.docx -o keydopandoc.pdf` Both of them returned the same error message when I had not used the lua file.    Does the lua file need to be put in some specific DIR?

Comment: Maybe there is another table with similar problems. The above script is too crude to fix those. The given filter is a bit specialized for the table in the question. If you can, merge the nested tables into the topmost table. I'm afraid the only real fix will be to resolve the issue in pandoc.

Comment: You are right. I forgot to test the lua with the table alone in a docx. And the lua successfully make it! Great. Thanks for helping me understand the issue, and it's no big deal for not being able to convert the docx I have in hand now cause most documents I get won't have tables LOL.

Comment: Happy to hear that its still helpful despite not solving the problem completely.